# How to put where condition in sql for fetching records from a column that has date and time in UTC format?

Tags: sql, oracle, date-format, date-comparison

I have some data in one of the column `lastmodified` that is in UTC format. Sample data below.

**lastmodified column (sample data):**

```
05-NOV-15 08.44.00.682392000 PM
05-NOV-15 08.43.00.808086000 PM
06-NOV-15 06.15.01.035835000 PM
06-NOV-15 06.14.00.694774000 PM
07-NOV-15 04.26.00.851745000 PM
07-NOV-15 04.26.00.690437000 PM
08-NOV-15 04.25.00.850166000 PM
08-NOV-15 04.25.00.683356000 PM
09-NOV-15 04.24.00.821617000 PM
09-NOV-15 04.24.00.768993000 PM
10-NOV-15 04.23.00.804560000 PM
10-NOV-15 01.20.00.501400000 PM
```

**Query:**

```
select *
  from my_table
 where trunc(lastmodified) = to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yy');
```

The above query works, but does not provide me what I want. How can I get all the records above `10-NOV-15 01.00.00` date-time?

Comment: Is the data type of the  `lastmodified` column TIMESTAMP or VARCHAR2?

Comment: The datatype is `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: You are comparing a string (`to_char(sysdate,...)`) to a timestamp. Don't do that. You need to use `trunc(lastmodified) = trunc(sysdate)`

Comment: Is `10-NOV-15 01.00.00` also in UTC or in your local time?

Comment: @Wernfried - UTC time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the datatype of `lastmodified` is `TIMESTAMP` you should be able to do

```
SELECT *
  FROM MY_TABLE
  WHERE TRUNC(LASTMODIFIED) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Or, if you really want to get records >= 10-NOV-15 01.00.00 you could use

```
SELECT *
  FROM MY_TABLE
  WHERE LASTMODIFIED >= TO_DATE('10-NOV-15 01.00.00', 'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SS')
```

Best of luck.